# `wrong type argument: number-or-marker-p, nil` after upgrading auctex

Tags: auctex, debugging

After upgrading to `auctex-13.0.1` I am getting the error `wrong type argument: number-or-marker-p, nil` whenever I try to compile a latex document in emacs.

Activating `toggle-debug-on-error` and issuing `C-c c latex` in a minimal latex document gives the following output:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument number-or-marker-p nil)
  TeX-active-master-with-quotes(t t nil t)
  apply(TeX-active-master-with-quotes (t t nil t))
  TeX-command-expand("%`%l%(mode)%' %T")
  TeX-command("LaTeX" TeX-master-file nil)
  TeX-command-master(nil)
  funcall-interactively(TeX-command-master nil)
  call-interactively(TeX-command-master nil nil)
  command-execute(TeX-command-master)
```

Any ideas what's wrong here?

I'm quite sure it's not the file I'm using. Any minimal document throws the error. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Hello.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please search this site for that error message. There are many occurrences, and most likely at least one is a duplicate of this question.

Comment: @Drew I've been searching this site, google, tex.stackexchange, and lots of other sites for hours. Yes, others have bumped into this error message. I haven't come across a post that's been helpful to me though. Maybe I missed something? Maybe you could point me in the direction of a post that would help? I'd happily see this marked as a duplicate if there's a legitimate duplicate. Otherwise, I'd like this question to stay posted because I'm hoping someone interested in helping me comes across it.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this (with auctex-13.0.1).  Can you supply a minimal LaTeX file that demonstrates the behaviour?

Comment: @FranBurstall Thanks for looking at this. Every latex file throws the error. I'll add one, but I'm sure it's not the file causing the issue.

Comment: OK, looks like an issue with yr config (I still can't reproduce the error).  Have a look at the Changes section of the auctex manual: looks like several variables like `TeX-expand-list` have changed their behaviour in v13 and that might cause yr error.

Comment: @FranBurstall Ok thanks. I'll look at the changes when I get a chance and see if I can't find something.

Comment: Occasionally, users experience problems while byte-compiling and installing/upgrading packages and the error(s) is/are within one or more of the `*.elc` files.  It is next to impossible for mere mortals to find the error within such a file.  Try removing the `*.elc` files of the relevant package and reboot Emacs, and see if the problem persists.  If the problem is gone after that test, then either re-byte-compile the directory(ies) applicable, or reinstall the package [and if so, figure out whether the old package needs to be removed prior thereto and research how to do so, e.g., manually] ...

Comment: If you looked at other posts about this error message and they weren't relevant here, great. Thanks for doing that.

Comment: @Drew Did you come across a post that would help me?

Comment: Remove your relevant (e.g. auctex) *.elc files, or at least move them out of your `load-path` for debugging. Then `M-x debug-on-entry TeX-active-master-with-quotes` and step through the debugger to see just what's expecting a number or marker and is getting nil instead. From that you may be able to figure out why it's getting passed nil.

Comment: This issue was also reported [here](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-auctex/2020-12/msg00001.html).  The problem is it is not reproducible and for the original reporter, the issue went away with AUCTeX 13.0.1.   May this is a [Heisenbug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug), but besides what @Drew suggested, I suggest you delete your AUCTeX installation via `package` and install it again after restarting Emacs, maybe that helps.

Comment: I ended up deleting AUCTeX (and all other packages depending on AUCTeX). After a reinstall things are working again! Maybe it was a zombie `*.elc` file floating around somewhere like @lawlist suggested.

Comment: Since there seems to be no "solution" to the problem - at least none we understand, please either delete the question or add an answer that says, in effect, that you reinstalled XYZ (whatever you actually did), and that solved the problem. Thx.

Comment: @ArashEsbati- Thank you for the comment. I faced the same issue. Removing auctex and then reinstalling helped.

Comment: delete then reinstall AUCTex is not working for me

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue since an update to auctex 14.0.2

Comment: I've completely reinstalled auctex and all of my packages. Nothing seems to work :'-(

Comment: Might be useful https://github.com/doomemacs/doomemacs/issues/5584